# MobileFirst JavaAdapter on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

Recently, I have registered on IBM Bluemix. I've created a Mobile Foundation Service which also creates a Container.

I started a new MobileFirst Project on Eclipse and deployed a JavaAdapter. The adapter works fine in my machine, and the endpoint url is http://localhost:10080/{My project name}/adapters/{My adapter name}.

I went to the mfpconsole of the Mobile Foundation Service (where the url is like {my custom name}.bluemix.net/mfpconsole and uploaded the same adapter.

My question is: What is the endpoint url where I can find my adapter?

I see in this documentation:(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_adapters_endpoint.html) that there's a "Context," but I don't know where to find this "Context" name. I received the message "Context Root not found."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Foundation on Bluemix is for version MFPF 8.0. You can also see the rest endpoints for you adapter by going into swagger docs in the console. I have attached a screenshot below.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into your adapter in the console and view the swagger docs (View Swagger Docs).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Dora wrote, please note that you're using Mobile Foundation service, which is based on MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, but creating Java adapters in MobileFirst Foundation 7.1

You may be able to deploy these adapters, but you will quickly find out that things have changed dramatically.

I suggest that you will follow the v8.0 documentation, including how to create adapters for v8.0: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/